# Разное поведение лямбда функции при объявлении с std::function и auto, оба раза некорректное

Tags: c++, функции, функциональное-программирование

Если я при объявлении лямбда функции использую слово auto, то получаю один результат (неверный):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{  
  auto a = [](int x)
    {
    return [&](int y) -> int
    {      
      return x+y;
    };
  };

  auto b = a(19);  
  std::cout << b(33) << std::endl;  
}
```

В консоль печатает : 66.
А должно печатать 52.
Если же я объявляю лямбда функции по всем правилам:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{  
  std::function <std::function<int(int)>(int)> a = [](int x) -> std::function<int(int)>
    {
    return [&](int y) -> int
    {      
      return x+y;
    };
  };

  std::function<int(int)> b = a(19); 

  std::cout << b(33) << std::endl;  
}
```

В данном случае в консоль печатает : 32799.
А должно печатать 52.

> g++ --version g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516 Copyright
>   (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the
>   source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for
>   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас неверный результат получается в обоих случаях, так как при `return [&](int y) -> int` будет захватываться ссылка на локальную переменную `x`, которая сразу же выходит из области видимости. Соответственно при вызове оператора () у `b` будет производится обращение по битой ссылке со всеми вытекающими. Если не обеспечиваете достаточную продолжительность жизни захватываемого объекта, то захватывайте по значению, а не по ссылке.

Comment: Действительно. Спасибо.